# What would the logic in the game loop of Lai Games "Stacker" be?

Tags: javascript, logic, game-loop

I'm trying to comprehend the logic behind this game:

[Lai Games - Stacker Arcade Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2hWr.jpg)

In my mind - Each loop will have a master Array.

eg. [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

and your player array:

eg. [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

and each tick the player will update

eg. [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]

and if the player matches the master - the stack grows.

eg. **PLAYER [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]**

eg. **MASTER [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]**

Otherwise, if there's a mismatch - the player array trims, and grows:

eg. **PLAYER [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]**

eg. **MASTER [0,0,1,1,1,0,0]**

eg. **RESULT [0,0,1,1,0,0,0]**

This is the best way I can think of - Is there are a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Each horizontal line can be treated as a binary number, 1 for lit, 0 for dark. Bottom row underneath the display all 1s. This makes all the operations really easy, moving left and right can be dealt with using bit shifts, and finding which digits stay on when moving up a row is as simple as ANDing the row with the row below it.